# Testing Datatstore service and getting null from a property filter query

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm writing a test for a filter of user by email on appengine datastore, here is the code:

```
class TestUser(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    # First, create an instance of the Testbed class.
    self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
    # Then activate the testbed, which prepares the service stubs for use.
    self.testbed.activate()
    # Create a consistency policy that will simulate the High Replication consistency model.
    self.policy = datastore_stub_util.PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy(probability=0)
    # Initialize the datastore stub with this policy.
    self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(consistency_policy=self.policy)
    self.testbed.init_memcache_stub()

def tearDown(self):
    self.testbed.deactivate()

def testQueryByEmail(self):
    user = User(name='jon', last_name='doe', email='jdoe@some.com', password='pass')
    user.put()

    fetched = User.query().filter(User.email == user.email).get()

    self.assertEqual(user.email,fetched.email)
```

And I'm getting `fetched = None` so the test fails.

If I query by id `fetched = User.get_by_id(key.id())` it gets the User. Maybe it is related to indexes? What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set `probability=0` on the `PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy`, which means your writes will never be visible to queries. You probably want to set it to 1 unless you're specifically testing behaviour under eventual-consistency. (I've never felt the need to do that, but ymmv.)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/indexconfig#Python_About_index_yaml),

> Indexes for simple queries, such as queries over a single property, are created automatically. Indexes for complex queries must be defined in a configuration file named index.yaml.

Follow the link for an example.

Comment: It also says "The development web server (dev_appserver.py) automatically adds items to this file when the application tries to execute a query that needs an index that does not have an appropriate entry in the configuration file. You can adjust indexes or create new ones manually by editing the file."